# Proving 2 languages are equal.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-expressions

I am quite new to Discrete Math and having lots of troubles solving the problems in it.

Currently, I am struggling with a problem:

Prove by induction that if $A$ and $B$ are regular expressions over one-letter alphabet and if $n$ is any natural, prove that languages $(AB)^n$ and $A^nB^n$ are equal.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried some simple example?  If the alphabet is $\{1\}$, $A=11$ and $B=1$, what do you get?

Comment: Sorry to say this but I am pretty much lost and do not know where to start my thing. I need some examples so I can follow it.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are as above and $n=2$, $(AB)^n = (111)^2 = 111111$ and $A^nB^n = (11)^2(1)^2 = 111111$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi can you please do an example with $A=a$ and $B=b$ where $a \neq b$ or $a$ and $b$ are not concats of each other?

Comment: @keoxkeox The alphabet is supposed to have only one letter; otherwise the claim is obviously wrong.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, ooh I got it by one-letter alphabet it is meant that the norm of the alphabet is 1, i.e. it has only one element

Comment: Then one should assume $A$ is a regexp which is concatenation of $n_a$ of the one-letter and $B$ has $n_b$ of the same, right @AlanBui?

Comment: I believe so @keoxkeox

Comment: @keoxkeox Not necessarily.  $A$ could be $1^*$, or $11^*$, or....  Same for $B$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi you are correct, but I thought $n_a=0$ or $n_b=0$ covers that?

Comment: @keoxkeox  If $A = 1^*$, then there is no $n$ such that $A = 1^n$.   Each word in $A$ is of the form $1^n$ for some $n$ (including $n=0$) but $A$ itself does not have that form.  As another example, consider $A=1 + 111$ (or $A = \{1,111\}$, depending on notation.)